# How to modify values of an object stored in a list

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, list, dictionary

I have a class that is instantiated at the beginning of each iteration of a loop. Inside the loop, it's attributes need to be populated with the row values of a table returned by a stored procedure. As I have to iterate through each column of every row, in order to know which attribute of the class needs to be assigned a value and when, I have a dictionary that maps the column names to an index. This index refers to a position in a list that stores an attribute of an instance of the class:

```
while (reader.Read() && reader.HasRows)
{
    Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
    List<string> subscrData = new List<string>
    {
        subscription.attr1, 
        subscription.attr2, 
        subscription.attr3, 
        subscription.attr4
    }


    Dictionary<string, int> columnDict = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"attr1": 0},
        {"attr2":1},
        {"attr3":2},
        {"attr4":3}
    }

    foreach (string colName in columnDict.Keys)
    {
        if (reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns[colName] == null)
            subscrData[columnDict[colName]] = "null";
        else
        {
            subscrData[columnDict[colName]] = reader[colName].ToString();
            nullsReturned = false;
        }
    }
```

I'm probably coming at this from more of a C++ approach as with that you could store references to the class instance an modify its attributes, but this doesn't work with C# because lists store the values.

**How can I restructure  this code so that I can modify the actual attributes of the class instance while still being able to check if each column returned from the stored procedure is not null?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the list for this case. You either want to add a method like setAttribute(string attributeName) to your class (and within it build a switch/case to modify the given attribute); or, use reflection to change an instance field given its name.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Hasan. But just for your information: to implement your approach you could make use of Lambda expressions to keep track of the references to your properties (= the attributes).

Something like this would work:

```
Subscription subscription = new Subscription(); 
List<Expression<Func<Subscription, string>>> subscrData = new List<Expression<Func<Subscription, string>>>
{
    a => a.attr1,
    a => a.attr2,
    a => a.attr3,
    a => a.attr4,
};

//E.g. To update attribute 3 you can do this:            
var prop = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)subscrData[2].Body).Member;
prop.SetValue(subscription, "test string", null);
```